# What are the real world differences between bind, systemd-resolved, dnsmasq, etc.?

Tags: dns, systemd, bind, dnsmasq

I'm trying to achieve three simple goals (on our CentOS8 server)...

1. local DNS resolution/caching
2. DNSSEC
3. DNSoverTLS

At first I went straight for `dnsmasq` because that was what it seemed most people were using in my research.  It was a trivial install and I was able to get it up and running in no time.  **#1 - check**

I then moved on to `DNSSEC` and eventually found that I just needed to add the following to my `dnsmasq.conf`...

```
conf-file=/usr/share/dnsmasq/trust-anchors.conf
dnssec
dnssec-check-unsigned
```

All seemed well and good, **#2 - check**

Finally I got to DNSoverTLS, and started to understand the difference between a `dnsforwarder` vs. a full DNS Server like `bind`.  It seemed that without installing yet another link in the chain, such as `stubby`, it was not something that was supported natively.  **#3 - soft fail**

I want as simple/easily maintainable solution as possible, i.e. fewer moving parts, so I started looking at `BIND9` since it's the defacto standard, but in doing that I also found `systemd-resolved` which is already installed and seemingly supports all three of my requirements. **#1,2,3 - Check**

My question is, in light of my three requirements, why would I not use `systemd-resolved`, what are the real-world differences or benefits of using one of the other two methods? I've seen some hate out there for `systemd-resolved`, but only because it wasn't truly secure due to a possible MITM vector, but that has since been dealt with from what I can see.

I've tried to find details comparing the three but everything is all about `bind` and `dnsmasq`, it's suprisingly hard to find anything other than a reference manual for `systemd-resolved`.

Thanks.

---

**EDIT:** So you've got a better idea of the circumstance, the server will be low usage, mail services, some file syncing, light web duty, for < 5 users typically, maybe the occasional bot/idiot trying to randomly penetrate it, etc. The only caveat, is that there will be many such instances, all running independently as standalone single tenant systems orchestrated centrally... so I'm looking for a simple but capable DNS system that provides modern privacy and security features like DNSSEC and DoT.

I'm not against a solution that has more parts, but I'm just looking for a justification if there is one for doing that.

That said, I just realized that CentOS8 is stuck on systemd v239, and the fully working DoT is not working until v245 according to the docs. So looking at Fedora 32 as an option.

Comment: *"In light of my three requirements, why would I not use systemd-resolved[?]"* - It feels like this question may need more focus. For instance, more "fully featured" resolvers can often cache more DNS query responses for a longer duration. But without knowing if that is an important consideration, it's a toss up as to whether it's even worth mentioning.

Comment: @Anaksunaman totally right, thanks for pointing out. I've added more details.